# Question about scanf problem in main function

Tags: c, scanf

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  //introduction
  printf("WELCOME TO PENTAGO!!!\n\n");
  int size = atoi(argv[2]);
  game* g = new_game(size, CELLS);
  printf("PENTAGO Board: (. : Empty, * : Black, 0 : White)\n");
  board_show(g->b);

  while(1){
    if(g->next == WHITE_NEXT){
      printf("White: \n");
    }
    if(g->next == BLACK_NEXT){
      printf("Black: \n");
    }
    //move
    //place marble;
    char move;
    printf("Please enter a move: ");
    scanf(" %c", &move);
    char a1 = move;   move++;   char a2 = move;
    pos p = make_pos(charToInt(a1),charToInt(a2));
    place_marble(g,p);
    board_show(g->b);

    //twist quadrant;
    printf("\nTo twist please enter quadrant q (1 : NW, 2 : NE,3 : SW,4 : SE) and direction d (c : clockwise, w: counterclockwise) in the given format: qd \nFor example 2w indicates a counterclockwise twist in the north east quadrant.");
    char entry;
    printf("Twist Entry: ");
    scanf(" %c", &entry);
    char q1 = entry ; entry++ ; char d1 = entry;
    twist_quadrant(g,charToQuad(q1), charToDir(d1));
    board_show(g->b);
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

I am experiencing a weird issue with the scanf function in my main function in c. As you can see, I included two scanf functions in my while loop. Through each iteration of the loop only the first scanf function would run while the second gets skipped over entirely. What could be the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the 2nd `scanf()` you expect something like "2w" but accept only a single char (`entry`),

Comment: `char q1 = entry ; entry++ ; char d1 = entry;` that's not how strings work in C.

Comment: You do not check any return value of the `scanf` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf(" %c", &move);
scanf(" %c", &entry);
```

People usually use `getch()` for such cases. It is more straight-forward.

```
char a1 = move;   move++;   char a2 = move;
char q1 = entry ; entry++ ; char d1 = entry;
```

These are really weird things. What are you trying to do?

```
char move;
char entry;
```

Good programming practice tells us that variables should be defined at the beginning of a function only. Usually compilers reject definitions in the middle of a function.

---

The comment:

> printf("\nTo twist please enter **quadrant q** (1 : NW, 2 : NE,3 : SW,4 : SE) and **direction d** (c : clockwise, w: counterclockwise) in the given format: qd \nFor example **2w** indicates a counterclockwise twist in the north east quadrant.");

asks the use to provide 2 non-white-space characters. One is consumed by the second `scanf()` (the one immediately after the comment), while the other remains in the buffer. It is then consumed by the first `scanf()`. That is why you have the "illusion" that some `scanf()`'s are not executed.

---

Which keys do you use for movement? Some keys (e.g. arrows) actually generate a sequence of 2 characters: the first is always 0x00 and the second is specific for each key. This could be another source of amazement.

---

You do not handle properly the situations when the key is not one of the expected keys. In those cases, entire chunks of code should be skipped and the loop restarted.